# Catkin Tools: How to include source file from another package?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, cmake, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Hydro, Catkin Tools]

I have a number of packages in my source tree and  `catkin_make` successfully builds all of them, but takes a long time.  So whilst I'm continuing with my developments, I'm using `catkin build` instead.

The package I'm trying to build with `catkin tools` (package3) has a couple dependencies (package1 & package2) which are successfully built.  package3 itself, however, fails because the ${package2_SOURCE_DIR} variable returns an empty string and the source file I need from package2 can't be located.  The associated header files are found successfully because ${package2_INCLUDE_DIR} mentions the correct path (along with a number of other paths). *I'm not sure why _INCLUDE_DIR is working, but _SOURCE_DIR isn't.*

What I've discovered is that under `catkin_make`, CMake variables are global across the whole build. (Though this might not be an entirely correct statement.)  Under `catkin build`, package variables are kept local (even when I use `find_package(package2)`).

I would like to avoid hard coding an absolute path into my add_executable() statement, but I don't know how to get the `<package_name>_SOURCE_DIR` for package2.  My `add_executable()` statement, which works with `catkin_make` is:

```
add_executable(programA
    /src/programA.cpp
    ${Package2_SOURCE_DIR}/src/common.cpp
)
```

Is there a variable I can use that points to the catkin workspace?  I don't mind using a line like:

```
${catkin_ws_BASE_DIR}/src/package2/src/common.cpp
```

Anyone able to help me solve this in an elegant way?

Cheers,
Nap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217214/catkin-tools:-how-to-include-source-file-from-another-package?/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2015-09-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on 2015-09-07**:
Have you tried `${Package2_DIR}` (note: not SOURCE_DIR)?

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-09-07**:
`${package2_DIR}` returns: "/home/me/catkin_ws/devel/share/package2/cmake"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Anyone able to help me solve this in an elegant way?

Do you have a reason for wanting to directly include src files from `package2` into `programA`?

We normally (not just in ROS / with catkin) solve these kind of things by creating a library in `package2`, making sure `package2/include` is on the include path of whatever pkg `programA` is in, and then linking `libpkg2` to `programA`.

I would consider using libraries like this an *elegant way*.

---

Edit:

> Whilst your suggestion is fine, it's not the way we handle this kind of situation in our Lab, when using our own build system. Catkin/CMake is not our preferred tool chain. With that in mind, I prefer to reference it in the other package than create a duplicate.

Well, I must say that I wouldn't put recompiling source files for every target under *elegant*, but just to answer your question:

it would appear the variable `<pkg_name>_SOURCE_PREFIX` contains the path your are looking for. I haven't used this myself, and afaict it is undocumented (which means it may stop working / be removed at any time), but it should get you what you are after. Note that you must've `find_package(..)` the pkg first, or have included it in a `find_package(catkin .. COMPONENTS ..)` call.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-09-07**:
Thanks gvdhoorn. Whilst your suggestion is fine, it's not the way we handle this kind of situation in our Lab, when using our own build system.  Catkin/CMake is not our preferred tool chain.   With that in mind, I prefer to reference it in the other package than create a duplicate.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-09-07**:
Thanks, `<pkg_name>_SOURCE_PREFIX` worked.
Would you be so kind as to provide a link to the page where you found that info?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-07**:
As I said, the variable is undocumented. I found it by searching a `devel` and `build` space.

What you are doing is also really not recommended (it's brittle). See [catkin_tools/issues/83](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/83) for some discussion and also an alternative.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-09-07**:
A package A should never depend on the source directory of package B. E.g. you won't be able to release these packages because B has been built and installed and afterwards the source folder has been removed before A is being compiled.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-09-07**:
As @gvdhoorn suggested you should either build a library and install the headers or if you really don't want to do that install the source files and compile them in the downstream packages.